# Fill across a data frame based on a value in a column in R

Tags: r, dataframe, na

I have a data frame as below:

| y | m0 | m1 | m2 | mn |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 | NA | NA | NA |
| 2 | 15 | NA | NA | NA |
| 3 | 25 | NA | NA | NA |

I would like to fill the value in m0 across the number of columns specified in y. Desired result is:

| y | m0 | m1 | m2 | mn |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 | 5 | NA | NA |
| 2 | 15 | 15 | 15 | NA |
| 3 | 25 | 25 | 25 | 25 |

Appreciate any guidance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A **base R** approach using `sapply`. `colbeg` defines the first column where NA has to be replaced. Can be hard coded but I suspect that it should be adjustable for the real data.

```
colbeg <- 3

data.frame(t(sapply(seq_along(df$y), \(x){
  df[x,colbeg:(colbeg - 1 + df$y[x])] <- df$m0[x]; df[x,]})))
  y m0 m1 m2 mn
1 1  5  5 NA NA
2 2 15 15 15 NA
3 3 25 25 25 25
```

Answer (score 1):

You can first transform your data to a "long" format, then replace `NA` with the `first` value when the count of `NA` is within `y`.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  pivot_longer(-y) %>% 
  mutate(value = ifelse(is.na(value) & cumsum(is.na(value)) <= y, first(value), value),
         .by = y) %>% 
  pivot_wider()

#> # A tibble: 3 × 5
#>       y    m0    m1    m2    mn
#>   <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
#> 1     1     5     5    NA    NA
#> 2     2    15    15    15    NA
#> 3     3    25    25    25    25
```

Answer (score 0):

Base R:

```r
lapply(setNames(0:2, paste0("m", 0:2 + 1)), function(z) if (z < 1) quux$m0 else c(rep(NA, z), tail(quux$m0, n = -z))) |>
  as.data.frame()
#   m1 m2 m3
# 1  5 NA NA
# 2 15 15 NA
# 3 25 25 25
```

You can either replace the columns or cbind them.

```r
quux[,0:2 + 3] <- lapply(setNames(0:2, paste0("m", 0:2 + 1)), function(z) if (z < 1) quux$m0 else c(rep(NA, z), tail(quux$m0, n = -z))) |>
  as.data.frame()

quux <- cbind(
  quux[,1:2],
  lapply(setNames(0:2, paste0("m", 0:2 + 1)), function(z) if (z < 1) quux$m0 else c(rep(NA, z), tail(quux$m0, n = -z)))
)
```

(I'm consistently using `0:2` and offsets to show how things would be changed for an arbitrary number of columns.)